# Dart - About executing multiple lines of processing in an if statement

Tags: loops, if-statement, dart

I am trying with `https://dartpad.dev/`.

I want to execute multiple processes in the if statement as follows.

```dart
void main() {
  List<dynamic> arrayA = [1, 2, 3];
  List<dynamic> arrayB = [1, 2, 5, 6];
  arrayB.forEach((m) => {
        if (!arrayA.contains(m)) {
          print(m);
          break;
        }
      });
}
```

However, the following error is output when the process of multiple lines is written in the if statement.

```
Error compiling to JavaScript:
main.dart:6:19:
Error: Expected '}' before this.
          print(m);
                  ^
Error: Compilation failed.
```

What I want to do is following..

(Temporarily, the process you want to execute is "A" (in this case, "print(m);"))

-In the loop, execute the processing "A" when the condition is true

-I want to escape from the loop after executing the first "A".

Then, please tell me what is wrong in the code and how to write it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the `break` statement inside a lambda. You could use `break` only inside loops, like `for` or `while`. Another problem is a wrong syntax of your lambda declaration (at first, and even sometimes now I have the same problem, and it requires some time to figure out what is wrong. I think it's dart's problem and it should have a more precise error message in such a case). You've combine syntax of short lambda and long lambda declaration. Short one should be like that:

```
(m) => print(m);
```

Long lambda should look like that:

```
(m) {
    print(m);
}
```

So the fixed code could look like that:

```
void main() {
  List<dynamic> arrayA = [1, 2, 3];
  List<dynamic> arrayB = [1, 2, 5, 6];
  
  for (final m in arrayB) {
    if (arrayA.contains(m)) {
      print(m);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

And also, I should mention, that using a `dynamic` is not a good idea. It's better to use `int` type here:

```
List<int> arrayA = [1, 2, 3];
List<int> arrayB = [1, 2, 5, 6];
```

Comment: The reason for the odd error message is that the compiler sees `(m) => { if (...) print(m) ...` as a function returning set or map literal, with a conditional element, and then it doesn't expect a `;` at the point where it occurs.

Comment: @lrn now I see, thank you for pointing it out to me.

Comment: @ChessMax
Thank you for your reply! The problem is solved!
I didn't understand much about the difference between loop and lambda.


Thank you for pointing out the type!
Actually, I didn't want to use `dynamic`, but since the response type of the API used in the project I was facing was undefined, I am temporarily using `dynamic`. .. ..


@lrn
I see, the error message came from an error in the lambda notation...
Thank you for the information!